# How can I correctly configure GitHub Pages for individual web-related repositories?

Tags: github, web, github-pages

I've got a few GitHub repositories with some basic web pages in them, and I want to get GitHub Pages up and running for each of them so I can show off my work online. However, I'm a bit lost on how to do this properly for each repo, I'm kind of new in the Github things.

Can anyone give me some guides for setting up GitHub Pages? And if there are any tips or things I should keep in mind to make sure everything goes correctly, I'd really appreciate the advice.

You can check out [my GitHub profile](https://github.com/geroxima/) if that helps. Thanks a bunch in advance!

I attempted to configure my GitHub Pages, and it worked "well." However, currently, one of my repositories serves as the main page when I visit [this link](https://geroxima.github.io/), while the other is accessible [here](https://geroxima.github.io/wordle). I want them hosted separately under /calculator and /wordle respectively. How can I achieve this?